# Zend Framework e Symfony

Tags: zend, symfony

Comecei a estudar o Symfony 2 e percebi que ele é muito produtivo para o desenvolvimento de sistemas, mas tem pessoas que falam que o Zend Framework 2 é o melhor framework em PHP. Gostaria de saber quais são as principais diferenças entre o `Symfony 2` e `Zend Framework 2`?

Comment: O `Zend Framework 2` provavelmente deve ser bem falado por ter um relacionamento direto com o PHP (pois é o seu mantedor). Os dois são frameworks modularizados. O `Symfony` parece ter uma curva de aprendizagem menor do que a do `Zend 2`. O Zend é muito difícil!